# Parent and child selector use

Tags: jquery, css

How do I get the parent below the child?

```
<div class="largezindex">
   <span>mgmg</span>
   <span>mgmg</span>
   <span class="smallzindex">mgmg</span>
</div>
```

css

```
  .largezindex{
     zindex:1000;
     position:relative;
     hieght:300px;
     backgorund-color:#f0f0f0;
     color:red;
     width:300px;
   }

   .smallzindex{
      z-index:1;
      position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: -25px;
  }
```

Comment: Here on Stack Overflow we say "thank you" by upvoting and "that worked" by accepting the answer. The edit removed your "thank you" because the preemptive gratitude is implied. He was thanked for editing you question with +2 reputation. The main point is we try to keep it slim and to the point. Gratitude and manners are awesome but we keep this chatter down to avoid taking away from the important stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select the child depending on the parent of it. You should use it like this

```
parent child {
   // properties here...
}
```

In your case it would be like this

```
.largezindex .smallzindex {
   // smallzindex properties here...
}
```

Comment: how use my friends i want parent below child is hide

Answer (score 1):

**jquery**

```
$('.smallzindex').parent(); // will give u the parent of smallzindex
$('.smallzindex').parent().eq(number); // will give u nth parent of child
```